# How to configure CORS of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Using Cloudflare?

Tags: cors, cloudflare

I am having this error when submitting file:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dd-demo.abc.com:8443/api/token' from origin 'https://dd-demo.abc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do i resolve this using Cloudflare?

Some article showing old Cloudflare interface and it doesn't quite work when using

```
PageRules
```

with

```
Disable Security setting.
```

If possible I don't want to disturb the backend server setting.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure CORS settings (and any other headers) in the Rules -> [Transform Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/) section. Here you need to go to the "Modify Response Header" tab and create a rule.

It should looks something like this (I didn't test that rule):
[image]

This is only example, and for production use you need to have https://dd-demo.abc.com as a value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin