# Terraform provisioned AWS API GatewayV2 not sending CORS Headers back to Options request

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cors

I have a web application that is trying to engage with a rest API hosted by AWS using an api gateway_v2, provisioned using terraform. The web application is at https://something.example.com. The api is at https://somethingElse.example.com. I should also mention that the API is proxied by CloudFlare.

When I make the following request, it fails due to CORS errors

```
doesAlertHaveSR(id: string) {
    let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // #TODO - Assign this as a variable
    const url = 'https://example.com/mypath?id=' + id;
    xmlHttp.open('get', url, false);
    //Add auth token
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Token', 'my_token');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
  }
```

[image]

My terraform config for the API is below;

```
 resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "external_api_dev" {
      name          = "external_api_gateway_dev"
      protocol_type = "HTTP"
        cors_configuration {
        allow_origins = ["*"]
        allow_methods = ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
        allow_headers =[ 
                         "content-type",
                         "token",
                         "authorization",
                         "referer",
                         "sec-ch-ua",
                         "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
                         "sec-ch-ua-platform",
                         "accept",
                         "accept-encoding",
                         "accept-language",
                         "access-control-request-headers",
                         "access-control-request-methods",
                         "origin",
                         "sec-fetch-dest",
                         "sec-fetch-mode",
                         "sec-fetch-site",
                         ":authority",
                         ":method",
                         ":path",
                         ":scheme",
                         "user-agent"]
        max_age = 300 
      }
    }
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) answer and I understand the CORS preflight. Since the api and the web application are on the same domain, can I stop CORS from interferring or prevent the preflight? Requests are only accepted from the same domain.

If not, how do I configure the api gateway_v2 to respond to the CORS preflight correctly?

**Edit**
When I bypass the cloudflair proxy, I am now getting a 404 return with an error;

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So the request is being blocked by the CORS policy because of this missing header. How do I configure the API Gateway to return this header?

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots, those should be reproducible blocks of code. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I remember in the non v2 this was done with the: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_response with a response_parameters that looked like: `"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  = true` ... but not seeing that on V2

Comment: You mention `the API is proxied by CloudFlare` do you get the same if you call it directly?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda This was the issue. I should have thought of this.  If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Using Cloudflare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983353/how-to-configure-cors-of-access-control-allow-origin-using-cloudflare)

Comment: @Michael, appreciate your offer, but better just to close it as a duplicate to keep things clean

Answer (score 0):

The Proxy was the problem. Once I removed the proxy the api gateway responded to the calles properly for the CORS preflight.

The additioanl CORS problem I had after my edit was a red herring as I was getting a 404 from my request.